# $_GET problem in .html url

Tags: php, html, query-string

I have a url like this:

```
http://mysite.com/contact.html?id=5
```

I want to get the value of id in the url in my php file. I try `$_GET['id']` but it doesn't return anything.

How can I get it?

Comment: Please post your code (the relevant part). `$_GET['id']` is correct, so you don't seem to process the value correctly.

Comment: I guess it should be in a flie named contact.php

Comment: is `.html` server parsed as `.php`?

Comment: I use .htaccess, i think it is the problem

Comment: @hd: Could be, if it is not set up correctly. Please post the contents.

Comment: @Erik True. Unless he uses mod_rewrite, which is not likely the case here `;-)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that the file is `.html` instead of `.php`, so it will not be parsed by PHP. If you want PHP to also work on `.html`, add this like to your `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

I wouldn't recommend it, though, since it's not really standard. In most cases, you're better off just renaming the file to `.php`.

Answer (score 1):

The file you areaccessing in the URL is HTML. You need .PHP file to get the value from URL. Within HTML you can not get PHP Super Global value.

Try with

```
echo $_GET['id']
```

Or Check your getting GET values or not.

```
echo "<pre>";    
print_r($_GET);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing this echo $_REQUEST['id']

Answer (score 0):

if you are using php code then it will be more recommendable that the extension will be .php not .html..

convert file in to php file and then try ..

i think it will work..