# passing URL parameters through different pages

Tags: php, html, http, web

when users click on my ad on BING they get to

```
"www.mydomain.com/home.html?s1={MatchType}&s2={CampaignId}&s3={Query String}"
```

and BING replaces the parameters with values.
I want these values to pass along with the user when he navigates to certain pages on my site (f.e mydomain.com/product1.html), and even when he gets redirected to a different site (f.e offer.com/offer.html).
So on my home page I placed the specific links in the following manner:

```
www.mydomain.com/product1.html?s1=<?php echo $_GET['s1'];?>&s2=<?php echo $_GET['s2'];?>&s3=<?php echo $_GET['s3'];?>

www.offer.com/offer.html?s1=<?php echo $_GET['s1'];?>&s2=<?php echo $_GET['s2'];?>&s3=<?php echo $_GET['s3'];?>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, what am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: change page extension to products1.php & offer.php

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What does it do? What do you want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the file is .html instead of .php, so it will not be parsed by PHP.

```
If you want PHP to also work on .html, add this like to your .htaccess file:

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

OR

Rename File to products1.php & offer.php, Like:

```
www.mydomain.com/product1.php?s1=<?php echo $_GET['s1'];?>&s2=<?php echo $_GET['s2'];?>&s3=<?php echo $_GET['s3'];?>

www.offer.com/offer.php?s1=<?php echo $_GET['s1'];?>&s2=<?php echo $_GET['s2'];?>&s3=<?php echo $_GET['s3'];?>
```

Click this link [$_GET problem in .html url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580375/get-problem-in-html-url) to know more

Comment: @YotamFlohr: If it worked, please tick the answer. Because it will help other people to find it corretly. Thanku. I'm Glad to help.